# How to get the points of the rectangular area

Tags: c#, winforms

I searched on the web, but I still in the dark. I need to get the points of  the rectangular area when the user highlight the text in the control on my C# Winform project.  For example the user highlight as the image below. I need the below point to draw the box.

- **X1:** The horizontal co-ordinate of the bottom-left corner.
- **Y1:** The vertical co-ordinate of the bottom-left corner.
- **X2:** The horizontal co-ordinate of the bottom-right corner.
- **Y2:** The vertical co-ordinate of the bottom-right corner.
- **X3:** The horizontal co-ordinate of the top-right corner.
- **Y3:** The vertical co-ordinate of the top-right corner.
- **X4:** The horizontal co-ordinate of the top-left corner.
- **Y4:** The vertical co-ordinate of the top-left corner.

I only know I can get the start points (X4 and Y4) on mouse down event and end points (X2 and Y2) of the mouse up event.  Hope someone can show me example or link to do it.

[image]

Comment: In your picture above, what part of the picture do you consider the "top-left" corner? The corner near the word "quia", or the corner near the word "qui"? Likewise, what part the "bottom-right"? Since there is not actually a simple rectangular area in your picture, it's really hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: If you have (x2, y2) and (x4, y4), wouldn't the other coordinates, more or less, be (zero, y2) and (control.Width, y4)?  Otherwise, you can get a characters position using the GetPositionFromCharIndex function to get those other coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the MousDown and MouseUp Coordinates you can read the following to determine the screen/client coordinates if that is what is required.

To use the 2 points to create a rectangle:

```
Rectangle theRectangle = new Rectangle
    (new Point(v1, v2), new Size(v4, v5));
```

On the other hand I don't really understand what rectangle area you are referring to, exactly as peter-duniho commented on your post.

**Screen Coordinates**

A Windows Forms application specifies the position of a window on the screen in screen coordinates. For screen coordinates, the origin is the upper-left corner of the screen. The full position of a window is often described by a Rectangle structure containing the screen coordinates of two points that define the upper-left and lower-right corners of the window.

**Client Coordinates**

A Windows Forms application specifies the position of points in a form or control using client coordinates. The origin for client coordinates is the upper-left corner of the client area of the control or form. Client coordinates ensure that an application can use consistent coordinate values while drawing in a form or control, regardless of the position of the form or control on the screen.
The dimensions of the client area are also described by a Rectangle structure that contains client coordinates for the area. In all cases, the upper-left coordinate of the rectangle is included in the client area, while the lower-right coordinate is excluded. Graphics operations do not include the right and lower edges of a client area. For example the FillRectangle method will fill up to the right and lower edge of the specified rectangle, but will not include these edges.

**Mapping From One Type of Coordinate to Another**

Occasionally, you may need to map from screen coordinates to client coordinates. You can easily accomplish this by using the **PointToClient** and **PointToScreen** methods available in the **Control class**. For example, the MousePosition property of Control is reported in screen coordinates, but you may want to convert these to client coordinates.